# How to get the height of the draggable bar in a scrollviewer?

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

I am trying to get the distance in pixel between the top of the control and the middle of my vertical scrollbar (not all the scrollviewer, only the bar you can drag to scroll the control).
I don't understand which property i should use.
This is the code i wrote:

```
double barHeight = /*to do*/;
double barUpperEdge = scrollViewer.VerticalOffset;

double distance = barUpperEdge  + (barHeight/2);
```

Another question: which is the mesurament unit of `scrollViewer.VerticalOffset`? If it isn't in pixel what cast should i do?

Comment: Sounds tricky for sure... what do you need this information for? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to move a `TextBlock` up and down at the side of the bar.

Comment: *which is the measurement unit of `ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset`?*... pixels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate that value from the [`IScrollInfo` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.iscrollinfo(v=vs.110).aspx). The [`ScrollViewer` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer(v=vs.110).aspx) implements this interface and exposes the relevant properties that you need to use. As far as I can remember, you need to utilise three properties:

> `ExtentHeight` - Gets a value that contains the vertical size of the extent.
>
> `ViewportHeight` - Gets a value that contains the vertical size of the content's viewport.
>
> `VerticalOffset` - Gets a value that contains the vertical offset of the scrolled content.

To explain a little further, the `viewport` relates to the visible area of the `ScrollViewer` and the `Extent` represents the total size of the scrollable area. The `VerticalOffset` describes the amount that the scrollable content has been scrolled. Using these three values, you should be able to calculate your required values that relate to the `ScrollBar`. Try something like this:

```
double barHeight = ViewportHeight * scrollviewer.ActualHeight / ExtentHeight;
```

---

UPDATE >>>

Please note that it is generally bad practice to use constant values in your calculations. Microsoft have exposed many common properties for this very reason. In your case, I believe that you can make use of the [`SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarButtonHeight` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.verticalscrollbarbuttonheight(v=vs.110).aspx), although you may need to add something to accommodate `Padding` and/or `Margin` values:

```
double barHeight = ViewportHeight * (scrollviewer.ActualHeight -  2 * 
    SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarButtonHeight) / ExtentHeight;
```

You know... I've just thought of something... you *may* even be able to get your required thumb `Height` from these `SystemParameters`... you *could* try the [`SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarThumbHeight` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.verticalscrollbarthumbheight(v=vs.110).aspx), although I don't think that it will work with custom `ScrollBar`s.

Comment: Yes! `barHeight = ViewportHeight*(scrollviewer.ActualHeight-40)/ExtentHeight`
-40 because in actual height there are the two arrows up and down of the scrollbar

Comment: +1 Thanks for updating... I didn't have time to work out exactly what the calculation should be... I'll update the answer for future users.